# Show that $\operatorname E\left(\frac{\widehat{E} \widehat{E}^T}{n-q}\right) = \Sigma$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

We have $Y = X\beta+E,$ $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times q}$ and has rank $q,$ $n\gg q,$ $\beta\in\mathbb R^{q\times1},$ $E$ is a random vector taking values in $\mathbb R^n,$ $\operatorname{E}(E)=0\in\mathbb R^n,$ $\operatorname{var}(E) = \Sigma,$ so $\Sigma$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ real matrix. The variance $\Sigma$ is strictly positive-definite. As usual the hat matrix is the $n\times n$ matrix $H = X(X^T X)^{-1} X^T,$ of rank $q,$ which is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $X.$ And the vector of observable residuals is $\widehat E = (I-H)Y.$

The question is how to show that
$$\operatorname E \left(\frac{\widehat{E} \widehat{E}^T}{n-q} \right) = \Sigma$$

---

My Process:

1. I know the $\operatorname E(\frac{1}{n-q}) = \frac{1}{n-q}$
2. So I am left with $\operatorname E\left[\widehat{E} \widehat{E}^T \right]$
3. This simplifies to $\operatorname E[Y^T (I-H) Y]$
4. I don't believe I need to expand the hat-matrix $H$.

What I want to do at this point is introduce $\Sigma$ somehow. The only thing I can think of is to introduce something like $\Sigma^{1/2} \Sigma^{-1/2}$ or $\Sigma \Sigma^{-1}$ but I'm not sure where or how to introduce this.

EDIT: Sorry for lack of clarity. This is a MULTIVARIATE STATISTICS problem. I've been so focused on just this that I forgot that other math exists :'D

$\Sigma$ is the Covariance Matrix. $n$ is the number of observations. $q$ independent variables. $\widehat{E}$ is the estimator for the error matrix.

Comment: Too much necessary explanations to your notations are missing. For example, what is $E$, what is $\hat{E}$, what is $\Sigma$? It looks like $Y^T(I - H)Y$ results in a scalar, why does its expectation equal to a matrix?

Comment: The main thing that's missing here is the distribution of $E,$ as opposed to $\widehat E.$ But some additional description of the problem should also be added. Presumably you have $Y=X\beta+E,$ where $X\in \mathbb R^{n\times q}$ and $n\gg q,$ and $\beta\in\mathbb R^{q\times 1},$ and $E$ is a random vector taking values in $\mathbb R^{n\times1}.$ One must of course have $\operatorname{E}(E) = 0 \in \mathbb R^{n\times1},$ and $\operatorname{var}(E) = \Sigma,$ but specifically what information about $\Sigma$ are you given? $\qquad$

Comment: . . . . . at this moment I'm not sure we need anything about $\Sigma$ beyond its being a symmetric matrix with real entries and strictly positive-definite. $\qquad$

Comment: ok, I've filled in the usual stuff in an initial paragraph.

Comment: Typically the values of $X$ and $Y$ are the observed data and the first task is to estimate the unobservable $\beta$ by least squares.

Comment: Again, did you notice that the left hand side of your equation is a scalar, while the right hand side is an $n \times n$ matrix? Before fixing this, how can you expect anyone to help you prove something wrong?

Comment: What I infer is that your response variable is multivariate ($p$-dim), so that your $Y$ is of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, $\beta$ is of $\mathbb{R}^{q \times p}$, and $E$ is of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$. The $\Sigma$, is definively not of size $n \times n$, but of size $p \times p$, representing the covariance matrix of a single response observation.

Comment: @Zhanxiong : I hadn't noticed that. It is obvious that what must have been meant is $\widehat E \widehat E^T$ rather than $\widehat E^T\widehat E.$ That is an $n\times n$ matrix. $\qquad$

Comment: I have take the liberty of changing $\widehat E^T \widehat E$ to $\widehat E \widehat E^T,$ since obviously that is what was meant.

Comment: @MichaelHardy With quite high confidence level,  I think he is talking about the [multivariate regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model). If we restrict ourselves in the ordinary regression setting, there is no such theorem.

Comment: @Zhanxiong : You may well be right, and if so, we should be able to figure out what is meant.

Comment: @Zhanxiong : Perhaps with just a bit more effort, we can get the original poster to clarify all this. But if you're right, it may be that $\widehat E^T \widehat E$ was right and that it's not a scalar.

Comment: Yes I apologize. I tried to find the category (The closest I found was Statistics). But I do mean the multivariate linear regression. The problem was stated accurately as presented. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'll get into the habit of providing more detail in the future. E.g., overall subject, subject of the chapter the question was asked on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have an $n\times n$ hat matrix whose rank is $q.$

The expected value $\operatorname E Y$ is in the column space of the hat matrix $H.$ Since $H^2=H,$ that implies $\operatorname E HY = \operatorname E Y.$ Therefore $\operatorname E ((I-H)Y) = 0.$

The fact that $H$ is symmetric and idempotent implies that $I-H$ is also symmetric and idempotent. Therefore $I-H = (I-H)^T(I-H).$ It follows that
$$
\operatorname{var}((I-H)Y) = (I-H)^T \Big( \operatorname{var}(Y) \Big) (I-H).
$$
At this point I'm wondering if you have some additional assumptions about the nature of the matrix $\Sigma = \operatorname{var}(Y).$ Very often one works with $\Sigma = \sigma^2 I,$ a positive scalar multiple of the identity matrix. In that case you'd have
$$
(I-H)^T \Big( \sigma^2 I\Big) (I-H) = \sigma^2 (I-H).
$$
Then you can say that since $I-H$ is a symmetric idempotent matrix of rank $n-q,$ there is some orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to which the matrix $I-H$ is transformed to
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ & 0 \\ & & 0 \\ & & & \ddots \\ & & & & 1 \\ & & & & & 1 \\ & & & & & & \ddots \\ & & & & & & & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where the number of $1$s on the diagonal is $n-q$ and the number of $0$s is $q.$ Hence $\widehat E^T\widehat E$ becomes a sum of squares of $n-q$ entries, each with expected value $\sigma^2.$

Comment: Oh dear.. This is not what I anticipated. Is there not a way to show it from $\hat{E}^T\hat{E}$ and use theorems to get $\Sigma$? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding something. My book has $E(e_i e_i^T) = \Sigma$
Can't that be used?

Ugh.. These proofs are so difficult for me. I apologize if I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Wait. OK I think I'm getting it. I'm still confused what happened when you created the orthonormal basis. What is that representing? I'm not familiar with such a matrix.

Comment: Also, why do we have $\sigma^2$ on the diagonal instead of $\sigma_{ij}$? My text says that $\Sigma = (\sigma_{ij})$

Comment: Except I imagine I can have i=j in which case $\sigma_{ii} = \sigma^2$ but why would my book write it this way since they only have the diagonal filled?

Comment: I've added some clarifying information to the question. Maybe I'll come back within a day or two to spell out this answer in more detail.